# Image scaling on hover

Tags: html, image, css

I have few images in HTML page and want those images to be scaled on hover. So I have written the below code which works well. However, right now images get scaled at their position so there are chances that it will get cut, so I want the scaled image to be placed at the center of the screen. Can someone help me with this?

**The Code:**

```css
.parentimage { 
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px; 
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
} 
.parentimage:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(4);
  -webkit-transform: scale(4);
  -o-transform: scale(4);
  -ms-transform: scale(4);
  transform: scale(4);
}
```

```html
<li style='display:inline;padding: 5px 5px;'><img style=' border: 5px solid white;width:150px;height:130px' class='parentimage' src='https://stanhub.com/tutorials/hover-to-zoom-image-effect/new-york.jpg' ></li>
<li style='display:inline;padding: 5px 5px;'><img style=' border: 5px solid white;width:150px;height:130px' class='parentimage' src='https://stanhub.com/tutorials/hover-to-zoom-image-effect/new-york.jpg' ></li>
<li style='display:inline;padding: 5px 5px;'><img style=' border: 5px solid white;width:150px;height:130px' class='parentimage' src='https://stanhub.com/tutorials/hover-to-zoom-image-effect/new-york.jpg' ></li>
<li style='display:inline;padding: 5px 5px;'><img style=' border: 5px solid white;width:150px;height:130px' class='parentimage' src='https://stanhub.com/tutorials/hover-to-zoom-image-effect/new-york.jpg' ></li>
<li style='display:inline;padding: 5px 5px;'><img style=' border: 5px solid white;width:150px;height:130px' class='parentimage' src='https://stanhub.com/tutorials/hover-to-zoom-image-effect/new-york.jpg' ></li>
<li style='display:inline;padding: 5px 5px;'><img style=' border: 5px solid white;width:150px;height:130px' class='parentimage' src='https://stanhub.com/tutorials/hover-to-zoom-image-effect/new-york.jpg' ></li>
<li style='display:inline;padding: 5px 5px;'><img style=' border: 5px solid white;width:150px;height:130px' class='parentimage' src='https://stanhub.com/tutorials/hover-to-zoom-image-effect/new-york.jpg' ></li>
```

Comment: Try to use JS in order to get the size of the view port, and do the math in order to move your element in the right place.

Comment: Why not use just CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Try following codes:

```css
.parentimage {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.parentimage:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(4);
  -webkit-transform: scale(4);
  -o-transform: scale(4);
  -ms-transform: scale(4);
  transform: scale(4);
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -194px;
  margin-left: -190px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style='display:inline;padding: 5px 5px;'><img style=' border: 5px solid white;width:150px;height:130px' class='parentimage' src='https://stanhub.com/tutorials/hover-to-zoom-image-effect/new-york.jpg'></li>
  <li style='display:inline;padding: 5px 5px;'><img style=' border: 5px solid white;width:150px;height:130px' class='parentimage' src='https://stanhub.com/tutorials/hover-to-zoom-image-effect/new-york.jpg'></li>
  <li style='display:inline;padding: 5px 5px;'><img style=' border: 5px solid white;width:150px;height:130px' class='parentimage' src='https://stanhub.com/tutorials/hover-to-zoom-image-effect/new-york.jpg'></li>
  <li style='display:inline;padding: 5px 5px;'><img style=' border: 5px solid white;width:150px;height:130px' class='parentimage' src='https://stanhub.com/tutorials/hover-to-zoom-image-effect/new-york.jpg'></li>
  <li style='display:inline;padding: 5px 5px;'><img style=' border: 5px solid white;width:150px;height:130px' class='parentimage' src='https://stanhub.com/tutorials/hover-to-zoom-image-effect/new-york.jpg'></li>
  <li style='display:inline;padding: 5px 5px;'><img style=' border: 5px solid white;width:150px;height:130px' class='parentimage' src='https://stanhub.com/tutorials/hover-to-zoom-image-effect/new-york.jpg'></li>
  <li style='display:inline;padding: 5px 5px;'><img style=' border: 5px solid white;width:150px;height:130px' class='parentimage' src='https://stanhub.com/tutorials/hover-to-zoom-image-effect/new-york.jpg'></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use position: **absolute** or **fixed** on hover and mange the position of the image according to screens.

Comment: Please consider that a more detailed answer, with some code sample, will give a better help to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

That indeed is possible, with a small edit in your current CSS.

```
.parentimage:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(4);
  -webkit-transform: scale(4);
  -o-transform: scale(4);
  -ms-transform: scale(4);
  transform: scale(4);

  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;

  margin-left: -75px;
  margin-top: -65px;
}
```

**Note:** This probably won't work as you expected. For example, the image is in the left top corner. The user hovers it and the image transitions to the center of the page. Because it moves, the cursor leaves the image, resulting in the image transitioning back to the top left. And then the cursor hovers again... etc.

See an example:

**https://jsfiddle.net/494krowe/2/**